# parse helm umbrella charts yaml via yq

Tags: parsing, yq

There is a need to get a version of the dependency chart based on the name in the Helm umbrella chart structure. How can it be done by using ***yq*** tool?
Input file example:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: application1
type: application
version: 0.1.1 
dependencies:
  - name: chart1
    version: v1.13.0
    repository: some-repo
  - name: chart2
    version: v0.11.0
    repository: some-repo
```

the expected output is the version based on the name of the chart. So I want to be able to pass the chart name(chart1/chart2) and get the version of it:

if name: chart1 output --> `v1.13.0`

if name: chart2 output --> `v0.11.0`

Comment: What is the yq version that you use? - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info

Comment: In your input both `chart1` and `chart2` appears. What should be the output in that case?

Comment: @Inian updated the question, hope it more clear now. version 4.27.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you could use a combination of `select` and `strenv` helpers to pass the required version argument as a string and retrieve the corresponding value of version

```bash
cname="chart1" yq '.dependencies[]|select(.name == strenv(cname)).version' yaml
```